# How to fit 4 figures (2 by 2) in a single slide with rmarkdown beamer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to fit the following four graphs (2 x 2) into a single side using rmarkdown beamer.
I tried the following code with plotting options including ggarrange() and plot_grid() to fail.
Any idea?

```
{r fig.align="center", fig.cap= "\\label{fig:asset} Firms' performances between the chaebol-affliated and indpendent firms (non-chaebols)", warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}

par(mfrow=c(2,2))

library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(extrafont)
library(gridExtra)


df <- read_dta(file = "aaa.dta")

fchaebol = factor(df$chaebol)

p1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x= year, y= asset, color = fchaebol, linetype = fchaebol)) + theme_bw() +stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean) 

p2 <-ggplot(df,aes(x= year, y= liability, color = fchaebol, linetype = fchaebol))+theme_bw() +stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean)

p3 <- ggplot(df,aes(x= year, y= sales, color = fchaebol, linetype = fchaebol))+theme_bw() +stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean)

p4 <- ggplot(df,aes(x= year, y= equity, color = fchaebol, linetype = fchaebol))+theme_bw() +stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean) 

p1
p2
p3
p4

#ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
#plot_grid(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` before your plots, like so:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
p1
p2
p3
p4
```

This will place all 4 of them in a 2x2 grid in the same plot. The `c(2,2)` is c(rows,columns) in the plot grid.

Comment: I did, but it does not make any difference.